# Passing arguments from PHP to a remote shell script

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I am executing a shell script located on a remote machine from a PHP script. So, let's say that PHP script runs on A and shell script runs on B (10.0.0.37).

I have the following code which runs well

```
$cmd = "ssh 10.0.0.37 /usr/tmp/script.sh";
exec($cmd, $output);
```

Now, I want to pass arguments to the shell script, preferably in JSON format.

The output of echo `json_encode($arg)` is as follows:

```
[{"original_name":"pdf_convert","changed_name":"pdf_convert_1"},{"original_name":"video_encode","changed_name":"video_encode_1"},{"original_name":"video_transcode","changed_name":"video_transcode_1"}]
```

I want to pass this as an argument to the shell script. So,

```
$data = json_encode($data);
$cmd = "ssh 10.0.0.37 /usr/tmp/script.sh $data";
exec($cmd, $output);
```

However, I see that the argument is not correctly read by the shell script. I tried putting single quotes around $data, didn't work. Also, tried using `escapeshellarg($data)`, still did not work.

## Edit

The output of `echo escapeshellarg($data)` is

```
'[{"original_name":"pdf_convert","changed_name":"pdf_convert_1"},{"original_name":"video_encode","changed_name":"video_encode_1"},{"original_name":"video_transcode","changed_name":"video_transcode_1"}]'
```

Also, if there is any other format which can be parsed easily in a shell script, then I would lie to use that format (not necessarily JSON). I see that I may have to use `'jq'` to parse json which needs me to install an additional package.

Comment: Can you post the code that *didn't* work when using [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)?

Comment: when you say "the argument is not correctly ready by the shell script", what do you mean? How are you reading the argument list?

Comment: I am writing the arguments to a temporary file on the same machine as the shell script. It contains  broken string.

Comment: Can you post that broken string?

Comment: It is just letter 'a'. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Bash isn't very good at accepting a JSON string in as arguments...

One way to get around bash trying to parse the arguments is for your php script to write the JSON string to a file, and for the bash script to parse that file with jq

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use serilaize to send the json data. Below is the code.

```
$data = json_encode($arg)
$data = escapeshellarg($data);
$data = serialize($data);
$data = str_replace('"','\"',$data);
$cmd = "ssh 10.0.0.37 /usr/tmp/script.sh $data";
```

I can now get the data in the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$json = '[{"original_name":"pdf_convert","changed_name":"pdf_convert_1"},{"original_name":"video_encode","changed_name":"video_encode_1"},{"original_name":"video_transcode","changed_name":"video_transcode_1"}]';

$cmd = $json;
$cmd = addslashes($cmd);
// addslashes does not escapes curly braces
$cmd = strtr($cmd, array('{' => '\\{', '}' => '\\}'));
$cmd = escapeshellarg($cmd);

$cmd = "ssh localhost echo $cmd";

echo "\n$cmd\n\n";

exec($cmd, $output);
var_dump($output)
```

**Shell (/tmp/1.sh):**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$1"
```

**Shell Output:**

```
ssh localhost /tmp/1.sh '[\{\"original_name\":\"pdf_convert\",\"changed_name\":\"pdf_convert_1\"\},\{\"original_name\":\"video_encode\",\"changed_name\":\"video_encode_1\"\},\{\"original_name\":\"video_transcode\",\"changed_name\":\"video_transcode_1\"\}]'

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(200) "[{"original_name":"pdf_convert","changed_name":"pdf_convert_1"},{"original_name":"video_encode","changed_name":"video_encode_1"},{"original_name":"video_transcode","changed_name":"video_transcode_1"}]"
}
```